# use pandas to parse csv,the result is wrong. the pandas version is 0.24.2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to parse a csv which has no headers and a delimiter('\t'),the result is wrong.All values of a row will be recognized as the first field and the other fields is Nan

```
csv_df=pd.read_csv(
    "./123",
    sep="\t",
    names=["month", "number", "age", "name", "column1"],
    quotechar='"',
    doublequote=True,
    skip_blank_lines=True,
    encoding="utf-8"
)     
print csv_df
```

```
the csv values is 

1  'Pete Houston'  'Software Engineer'  92

2     'John Wick'           'Assassin'  95

3   'Bruce Wayne'             'Batman'  99

4    'Clark Kent'           'Superman'  95

the parse result is 

                                          month number age  name
0  1  'Pete Houston'  'Software Engineer'  92     NaN  NaN   NaN

1  2     'John Wick'           'Assassin'  95     NaN  NaN   NaN

2  3   'Bruce Wayne'             'Batman'  99     NaN  NaN   NaN

3  4    'Clark Kent'           'Superman'  95     NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine for your csv example:

```
pd.read_csv("filename.csv", sep="\s+", quotechar="'", header=None,
    names=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

Instead of using `"\t"` as separator, better use `"\s+"`, which is more versatile. Also, there's a mess with your quote parameters.

Comment: thanks for your reply. it's my first time to write a question,please forgive me for writing a non-standard format.

Comment: if the values of the csv has a space ,your method is unuseful.the "\s+" separator will split a value into two values incorrectly.thank you for your help

Comment: Sure,  one should keep that in mind, but that's not the case

Comment: thanks.my question is that when the csv uses  "\t" as separator and the values has a space , the parsing result is wrong . The used method is read_csv("./123", sep="\t",
names=["a", "b", "c", "d"],quotechar='"',doublequote=True,skip_blank_lines=True,
encoding="utf-8")

Comment: When you specify the quotechar, spaces inside quotes are ignored. The problem with "\t" is that it's a hard tab, but often soft tabs are used instead. Soft tabs are not "\t", but sequence of spaces. Of course, if "\t" works fine, you can use it, but in my experience using "\t" as separator often causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because your csv file does not contain /t (tab) between the names.

I just replaced the spaces in each row with tabs and I ran your code which gave me following result:

```
   month          number                  age  name  column1
0      1  'Pete Houston'  'Software Engineer'    92      NaN
1      2     'John Wick'           'Assassin'    95      NaN
2      3   'Bruce Wayne'             'Batman'    99      NaN
3      4    'Clark Kent'           'Superman'    95      NaN
```

Comment: sorry.but in fact, the csv file will contain /t(tab) .I just started to get familiar with the use of this tool.Can you give a advice to solve this question.when the csv uses "\t" as separator and the values has a space , the parsing result is wrong . The used method is read_csv("./123", sep="\t", names=["a", "b", "c", "d"],quotechar='"',doublequote=True,skip_blank_lines=True, encoding="utf-8").
Thanks

Comment: The CSV file that you put in your answer did not contain tabs. I literally copied it and put it in a file and it gave me your first results. When I replaced the spaces with tabs it gave me the correct result. I did not change anything in your code. Therefor the problem was with the cvs file not the code your wrote.

Comment: sorry,i don't find to upload the csv file.now  in this condition ,how do i can solve th problem?
condition: when the csv uses "\t" as separator and the values has a space , the parsing result is wrong . The used method is read_csv("./123", sep="\t", names=["a", "b", "c", "d"],quotechar='"',doublequote=True,skip_blank_lines=True, encoding="utf-8")
Thanks